# Missing Android Studio git/linecount toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, view, statusbar, shortcut

Android Studio stopped displaying line count and current branch information in the bottom right portion of my program frame.

By default, Android Studio should show this information in the area I've circled in the screenshot below:

[image]

How can I tweak the settings to show this info again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please check that you have enabled status bar, from

**view --> status bar checked**

[image]

more guideline check [user-interface android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html)